# Force.com ide for Eclipse not refreshing reports/email templates from server correctly

Tags: force.com, reporting, ide, eclipse

My reports aren't refreshing from the server correctly via eclipse. Within eclipse, no matter what I do, I can't get the "subscribed to new reports" to show when I click the box. I've tried the following:

1. Add/remove metadata components --> Add/Remove click remove --> clicked refresh. At that poiint, I click reports and report types. The "Subscribed to new Report Types" shows (and mostly everything else) but NOT REPORTS or EMAIL!? Anyway, I apply the changes, and let it run, but the new reports still don't come
2. I created a new force.com project and DL'd the reports there. the new reports are there, but it's not subscribed for reports either.

I'm using Helios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this has to do with the package.xml file that Eclipse IDE uses to manage the project.

For certain metadata types, subscribing to new members doesn't work and the package.xml file has to contain the explicit items you want to download.  EmailTemplates and Reports are two such examples.

Put another way, in the `package.xml` file , this is all the specification required to subscribe to new Apex classes:  Note the * wildcard in the `members` tag

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
```

But for reports, it looks like this:

```
<types>
    <members>unfiled$public/myReport0</members>
    <members>unfiled$public/myReport1</members>
    ....
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
```

So, when you first built the project, using the Add/Remove Metadata components, you clicked the checkbox to get all Reports as were known when you built the project. The IDE amended the package.xml to explicitly enumerate each of those reports in the members tag, one per report.

As there is no * wildcard character, there is no way for the IDE to subscribe to new Reports.

*(Note, this is as of V30, the version I'm using as I write this)*

Thus, you have to manually go back to add/remove metadata components (don't forget to refresh the schema first) and choose the reports/email templates you need

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your `Eclipse` error logs? Believe it or not, officially, SF still only supports the `Java SDK 1.6` for the `SF Eclipse IDE` plug-in. If you continue having this problem, which sounds as though it's related to collecting metadata, you may find it's worth the effort to install a new instance of Eclipse to help you troubleshoot the problem.

First, you may want to make certain that you still have Jre6 Installed on your machine and that `Eclipse`'s `Installed JREs` which are located in the Menu under `Window` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Installed JREs`, points to the the path where `Jre6` is located at on your machine. Many of the Java updaters will remove references to `Jre6` when installing `Jre7`. You may need to go to Oracle's site and download the Java 1.6 Jre and reinstall it on your machine to get `Jre6` installed again on your machine if you no longer have it.

I had a very similar problem with one particular org when I accessed it on my XP-64 machine beginning early last summer. The only way I can get all the metadata in that Org is by continuing to keep `Jre6` on that machine. On my Windows 8.1 laptop, everything works fine with `Jre7`. Go figure!